# React: When do we have to memo the objects returned from a Hook?

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a Hook to return an object. Something like

```js
function useFoo() {
  const stuff = useStuff()
  const id = useId()
  const foo = {
     stuff,
     id,
  }

  return foo
}
```

I know that I can wrap `foo` inside `useMemo` to make its reference stable between re-renders so it can be safely included in dependency lists (by safely I meant it doesn't bust memorizations between re-renders).
But I don't like the costs of putting `useMemo` on things. The costs involve:

1. allocating the dependency list in memory
2. shallow-compare the dependency list (a o(n) process)
3. I have make sure anything used/referenced from that object also are memo'ed so as a result I have use more `useMemo` across the codebase

And at this point we can work around this issue by either:

1. make `foo` the state of the Hook. i.e.

```js
function useFoo() {
  const stuff = useStuff()
  const id = useId()
  const [foo, setFoo] = {
     stuff,
     id,
  }

  return foo // now we don't need to memorize it
}
```

But I guess this is unnecessary for various reasons but I cannot pinpoint exactly what the tradeoffs are for now.

2. putting it inside a ref, i.e. [the Latest Ref Pattern](https://epicreact.dev/the-latest-ref-pattern-in-react/)

The two workarounds are based on the premise that we obey the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` eslint rule, which is that we should include `foo` in dependency lists to avoid stale closure issues. For example, when `foo` is used inside `useEffect`, we need to include it in the dependency list to keep things in sync.

However I keep wondering if there are legit cases where we know for sure that we can safely omit `foo` from any dependency lists, i.e. ignoring `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` eslint rule (I know it is often discouraged).
For example, `foo` never changes during the lifetime of `useFoo`. Then in which case, it doesn't make any difference whether or not we include `foo` in a dependency list. Consequently, we don't even bother memorizing it in the first place in `useFoo`.

So my question is, are there any patterns or rules of thumbs that we can leverage to confidently **not** memorize `foo` as it doesn't matter whether or not we include it in any dependency lists?

Comment: Not sure if there is a pattern, but you should use it to his purpose. basically it remembers the inputs that were given to set function/method and if they are the same then instead of redoing the calculations/render it will just output the exact same as stored in memory. only when inputs are different then it will redo its function. That being said, its a clear rule that outlines - use it when the calculation/render/whatever is expensive in time/process standards. If it takes a lot of resources and time to do it - memo it. else - dont memo it.

Comment: Note that `useMemo` is just for performance optimization. *"You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee. In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components."*

I usually use refs for stable references of widely used hooks inside my application. If the hook is just used locally and it's return is not used in an dependency array, I simply return the object as is.